# Bluetooth streams and facebook's conceal library

Tags: android, facebook, encryption, bluetooth

i'm using the sample bluetooth chat app (https://android.googlesource.com/platform/development/+/eclair-passion-release/samples/BluetoothChat) with facebook's conceal library to (hopefully) encrypt the communication between devices. i changed the ConnectedThread constructor like this:

```
public ConnectedThread(BluetoothSocket socket, String socketType) {
        Log.d(TAG, "create ConnectedThread: " + socketType);
        mmSocket = socket;
        InputStream tmpIn = null;
        OutputStream tmpOut = null;
        InputStream cryptIn = null;
        OutputStream cryptOut = null;

        // Get the BluetoothSocket input and output streams
        try {
            tmpIn = socket.getInputStream();
            tmpOut = socket.getOutputStream();
      >>    cryptIn = crypto.getCipherInputStream(tmpIn,entity); << gets stuck on this line
            cryptOut = crypto.getCipherOutputStream(tmpOut,entity);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "temp sockets not created", e);
        } 
        catch (CryptoInitializationException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (KeyChainException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        mmInStream = cryptIn;
        mmOutStream = cryptOut;
    }
```

it gets stuck on that line, but without returning any kind of error or stack trace (it just freezes). also i'm passing the keychain name between the devices via beam to create the crypto object before calling ConnectedThread.

obviously i'm pretty new to android and conceal. thanks for the input.

Answer (score 0):

Reading from an network input stream is a blocking api call. I believe this was answered in https://github.com/facebook/conceal/issues/35